# Labview to google spreadsheet information transfer

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api, labview

I have been using LabVIEW to collect measurement data, and I would like to know if it is possible for LabVIEW to communicate the results to a Google Spreadsheet. If so, where could I find resources to learn how to make LabVIEW transmit information to the Google Spreadsheet ?
Thanks!

EDIT AND FOLLOW-UP- I used Jonathan's suggestion below and experimented with the LabVIEW http Post.vi. It's very simple, all you need to do is enter the URL of the Google form (replacing the final "viewform" with "formResponse") and a string with the data you want to enter (with rough syntax  = ). A big thanks for that answer, it was really helpful !

However, when I try to use this method for a Google form with more than one page, the data isn't read properly... The form is still sent but every field not present on the first page of the form remains blank on the Spreadsheet. I feel that this is somehow linked to the fact that in the Google form, the URL of all the pages after page 1 are the URL of page 1 with the final "viewform" replaced with "formResponse". Is this what is causing the error or is it something else altogether, and how can I fix it ?

Comment: if it doesn't work out, you can always write output to csv and import that into any spreadsheet application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of two ways to do this:

1. You can create a form in google spreadsheets. The form appears as an html document with standard  tags.  From here, I would use labview's http functionality to submit data to that form using a POST request.  This would be the easiest way to get data in there.
2. Using the Google Apps API, you can manipulate google spreadsheets and dump data in there directly.  This is going to be more complicated in terms of development time, but more configurable in the long run.  https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/#what_can_this_api_do  There are .net and java code examples throughout the documentation, so it would take some work to port this to LabVIEW, but it could be done.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, I will follow your advice.

Comment: Cool, let us know how it turns out

Comment: I simply used a .NET container in LabVIEW to display the Google form onto the front panel. A bit clumsy but it worked out well in the end.